# Append to previous line

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, printing, console

I'm doing folder/file processing in Python. To notify the user, I output some messages to the console. These messages look similar to this:

```
Creating folders...
DONE
Creating files...
DONE
All done!
```

This is fine if the process is short, but in my case, the process (and the messages) is not short. I don't want to waste new lines on the success/fail messages. I want them to look like this:

```
Creating folders... DONE
Creating files... DONE
All done!
```

The trick is to have "DONE" strings append to previous line after the specific task is completed. So, first I just see:

```
Creating folders...
```

and when the task is done, it becomes:

```
Creating folders... DONE
```

and moves on to the next task. I've tried not ending the lines, but it didn't work:

```
print("Creating folders... ", end="")
time.sleep(2) # fake process
print("DONE")
time.sleep(1)
print("Creating files... ", end="")
time.sleep(2)
print("DONE")
```

Well, it works, but both strings (task... result) show up at the same time (after the task is done). I don't see the transition I've mentioned above.

I've found another way, move to the start of the line and replace the string:

```
print("Creating folders... ", end="\r")
time.sleep(2) # fake process
print("Creating folders... DONE")
time.sleep(1)
print("Creating files... ", end="\r")
time.sleep(2)
print("Creating files... DONE")
```

This seems to produce the desired effect, but I'm repeating and extending the previous message. I'd rather just output the result, not repeat the task message again.

Is there a simpler solution to this?

---

Also, why doesn't the first method I've tried work? I print a text, and not end the line. After some time I add another text and this gets appended to the previous line, because there's no line-break. Since there's time difference between two prints, I should see the transition, but I don't. They get printed at the same time. Why is that?

Comment: What terminal are you using for this? There's something waiting for the output of the newline.

Comment: @ShioT Oh, it's Windows, so Command Prompt.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to flush the buffer after each print statement (that uses `end=""`) in order to ensure that the messages are pushed to the console immediately. See [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) documentation.

**Working Example with flush parameter of print function:**

```
import time

print("Creating folders... ", end="", flush=True)
time.sleep(2)  # fake process
print("DONE")
time.sleep(1)
print("Creating folders... ", end="", flush=True)
time.sleep(2)
print("DONE")
```

**Working Example with manual flushing:**

```
import time
import sys

print("Creating folders... ", end="")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(2) # fake process
print("DONE")
time.sleep(1)
print("Creating files... ", end="")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(2)
print("DONE")
```

**[See it in action!](https://repl.it/repls/FlusteredImpassionedAssignments)**

Comment: I've tested this, and it seems to work even if I just add `sys.stdout.flush()` after the first prints with `end=""`. No need to add it after `print("DONE")`s. So this makes me wonder. Does `print()` automatically `flush()` if the string ends with a line-break? o.O

Comment: `print` has a `flush` parameter, e.g. `print('eggs... ', end='', flush=True); time.sleep(1); print('and spam')`.

Comment: @eryksun I've JUST seen that :) Was about to comment. This makes it a lot easier.

Comment: @akinuri, for your follow-up question, the implicit flush for lines that end in a newline (i.e. line-buffering mode) is the default setting for the [`TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) instance that's used for `sys.stdout`, i.e. `sys.stdout.line_buffering == True`.

Comment: @eryksun Thank your for the comment, I've updated my answer using the flush parameter of the print function.

Comment: @DobromirM I might sound like nitpicking, but your answer needs to be further edited in light of the recent comments/explanations. First, you can add a link to [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) method. Second, there's no need to add `flush="True"` if the line already ends with a line-break. Third, there's no need to add `sys.stdout.flush()` after `print("DONE")` because it's already flushed; see "Second". I'm temped to accept this answer, but like I said, I guess I'm nitpicking :)

Comment: It's not nitpicking, I am happy to improve the answer. I've added link to the `print()` docs and removed the last flush as it is redundant. However the line break flushing does not work for me in PyCharm, so I would say always flush explicitly to ensure that it works in different IDEs.

Comment: @DobromirM, it could be that PyCharm runs Python with stdout redirected to a pipe, which by default uses full buffering. For example, from the command line run `python -c "import sys; print(sys.stdout.line_buffering)" | more`. It should print `False` because stdout is a pipe.