# Flushing print() with end=''

Tags: python

I would like to print words in one line (without newline), however, it seems that the print command doesn't flush after printing the word. That means, I have to wait until all words are written on the screen. Example:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for x in list:
    print(x, ',', end='')
    # do the rest
```

The output is `a , b , c` which is correct but as I said, it prints that on the screen at once. I want to see `a` first and then `b` and then `c` because the rest of the loop is time consuming and I want to be aware of the progress. How can I fix that?

Comment: `flush=True` ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append to previous line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55648799/append-to-previous-line)

Comment: If I read this [documentation about print](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp), there is an option to force flushing: `print(x, ' , ', end=' ', flush = true)`, what should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flush the buffer with the optional ['flush' argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).

That would look like this:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for x in list:
    print(x, ',', end='', flush=True)
    # Do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that `print()` writes to standard output by default, you can flush that:

```
# import sys

list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for x in list:
    print(x, ',', end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    # do the rest
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print